# Debian Cinnamon seems to have two window configurations for different applications

Tags: debian, cinnamon, theme, window-decorations, gtk3

The first window type is desired and is shown by the terminal window.
The second window type, shown by the gedit window (but also appears with some other applications), has a weird border configuration.

Firstly, tiling does not fill out half the screen properly and hovers from the screen's edges. Secondly, the control buttons have a different style that where the close window control does not touch the screen corner when the window is maximized or tiled to the right.

[image]

From what I've read, this seems to be a problem with gtk+3.12?

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Asking for possible causes and possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from GNOME 3.10, most of [GNOME core apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Core_Applications) uses *header bars (read [release notes](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.10/)), so they need GNOME's window manager [`Mutter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutter_%28software%29) in order to function. That's why on them apps, `Mutter` overrides Cinnamon's window manager (aka `Muffin`) - in your case `GEdit` using `Mutter` instead of `Muffin`, so it looks different from other applications.

About the tilling/maximizing with apps using `Mutter`, I think some how Cinnamon can't recognize them correctly, and count the shadow as a part of the window (I'm using Xfce and don't have no problem with tilling GNOME apps). Solutions: You might want to upgrade Cinnamon (I think you're using Debian Jessie with Cinnamon 2.2, which came out before the time *header bars* introduced, so an upgrade to Debian testing with Cinnamon 2.6 might help) or switch to [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php) or [LMDE](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php).

Comment: After some messing around I can say that none of these solutions work, including upgrading to a later Cinnamon (and I think this problem might be present in LMDE as well.

As you've said, the problem is with Gnome's Client-side-decorations that force the window to have their own styling. However, even by removing Mutter the problem is not fixed. 

There seem to be some tools for fixing this (e.g.: https://github.com/PCMan/gtk3-nocsd) but I've had no success with them/

So the best solution is probably to use alternative software (e.g. pluma instead of gedit)

Comment: Well, what I suggested just to fix tilling problems. But of course using non-gnome softwares could be a solution! :) Removing `mutter` won't work because these apps use pure Gtk+ now. `gtk3-nocsd` looks cool (I didn't know about that, trying now, but sure it isn't compatible with Debian Jessie), you may want to try it.